# Standard multi-signature transaction BitcoinCore

Tags: multi-signature

I created a transaction with a script for a Multi-Signature in the form of

```
M <A pubkey> [B pubkey] [C pubkey...] N OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

It is documented (https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#multisig) that this type of script would belong to the standard transaction types.

When i put that transaction into Bitcoin-CLI via decoderawtransaction, it says:

```
"vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00250000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "2 <PublicAdress 1> <PublicAdress 2> <PublicAdress 3> 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
        "hex": "XXX",
        "type": "nonstandard"
      }
    },
```

I then sent the transaction via sendrawtransaction and it is sent, accepted and mined successfully to the Blockchain but it seems to be invisible for my wallet.

Also when i send such a transaction to my BitcoinCore wallet, Bitcoin Core doesn´t notify me about it.

Is there simply no support in Bitcoin Core for that type of MultiSig transactions or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin Core will be default only treat M-of-N multisignature outputs as "yours" (contributing to your balance) if you own private keys to all N public keys. This is to prevent showing something as a balance which could be spent from under you.

If you instead of using a raw multisig output use P2SH the same rule applies, but in that case you're able to use `importaddress` to mark the outputs as yours regardless of whether you have access to the keys.

Once the outputs are treated as yours, you can use `signrawtransaction` to fully or partially sign for them.

Comment: Ok, shouldn´t it work then with this form?

`1 <PublicAdress 1> <PublicAdress 2> 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG`

Comment: It should work if both pubkeys are yours (= you have the private keys for them).

Comment: That brought me to a follow up question: [sharing-ownership-of-coins-via-multi-signature-transactions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67582/sharing-ownership-of-coins-via-multi-signature-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

You first say you created a script as

`M <A pubkey> [B pubkey] [C pubkey...] N OP_CHECKMULTISIG`

But then you continue with `decode...` output

`"asm": "2 <PublicAdress 1> <PublicAdress 2> <PublicAdress 3> 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG"`

Are you really using the public keys of the participants or their hex encoded addresses \ pubkey hashes?  It should come up as a multisig type if you're using the actual pubkeys.  Those are 33 or 65 bytes, and start with 02 or 03, or 04 respectively.